# Remove inline width attribute from HTML String in Java

Tags: android, jquery, html, webview

I am a little stuck. In an Android app I am currently working on, I download the HTML content of a Wordpress page via the Wordpress REST API to display it in a WebView. So far, so good. The problem is, that in the content, images are contained in a format somewhat like this:

```
<div id="attachment_5471" style="width: 685px" class="wp-caption aligncenter">
   <img class="size-full wp-image-5471" alt="alt-text" src="http://link-to-image.png" title="image-title-text" data-recalc-dims="1" />
</div>
```

The fixed width of the div containing the image causes my image not to be resized. I use [jquery.imagefit](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-imagefit-plugin/) to resize the image locally in my app to fit the device screen.

My idea to solve the problem is to remove the style=width:"*" from all divs that contain images. I believe that should be possible using Jsoup, however, I wasn't able to do it so far, so I came here for help.

Also, is that even a good approach, or is there a cleaner solution?

Consider that the div id is not the same for all images and pages. Also, note that I can not use

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

since it makes the text tiny.

I would appreciate any hint that leads me to solving this.

Comment: If you are OK with removing all `style=width:"*"` attributes from all tags (i.e, not only _divs that contain images_), then you can strip them out using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all inline styling with jQuery:

```
$('div').has('img').attr('style', '');
```

**[Demo Before the jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/UY9rx/1/)**

**[Demo After the jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/UY9rx/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to handle this in WebView, you can do it by overriding **`WebViewClient.onPageFinished()`**:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   String js = " .... "; // Here you can write your JavaScript to remove the style=width:"*"
   view.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
}
```

Like @zsaat14 said, you can use jQuery to achieve this:

```
String js = "$('div').has('img').attr('style', '')";
```

Or:

```
String js = "$('div').has('img').css('width', '')";
```